# centering using LESS mixin

Tags: css, less, mixins

This is from a LESS newbie.

I'm trying to horizontally center things using a LESS mixin, but it's not working. Is it my syntax? Other LESS settings are working.

LESS:

```
@mixin centerH {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#homepage_boxes {
    width: 25%;
    @include centerH;
    top: 0;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
#screen1 {
    .parent;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="screen" id="screen1">
    <div id="homepage_boxes" class="section group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3 clickable">
            <div class="part_head part1">Part 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3 clickable">
            <div class="part_head part2">Part 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3 clickable part_selected">
            <div class="part_head part3">Part 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like SCSS to me, not LESS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using SASS syntax, not LESS.

[LESS mixin syntax](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature).

I think this is what you want:

```
.centerH {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#homepage_boxes {
    width: 25%;
    .centerH;
    top: 0;
}
```

---

You actually used the correct syntax right below in your sample code:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
#screen1 {
    .parent;
}
```

The `.parent` styling behaves like a mixin but also targets a class.
If you wanted that to not work against a class and only work as a mixin, then you can use parenthesis to make it look like a function:

```
.centerH() {
```

which would allow other selectors to use `.centerH` as a mixin, but would not output `.centerH` itself into the resulting CSS file.